# pyspark SQL WHERE IN filter

Tags: sql, list, pyspark, filter, subset

I am trying to filter my data frame using a list of values using pyspark sql and the filter fails.
I am trying to understand if what I am trying is possible in the first place.

list = c['a-1','b-1','c-1','d-1']

df = spark.sql("select * from my_table WHERE Id IN list")

This doesn't work.
Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['a-1','b-1','c-1','d-1']
```

Join your list to get the string value concatenated with `,`

```
lst = ','.join(list)
```

Use string interpolation and use your joined lst here:

```
df = spark.sql(f"select * from my_table WHERE Id IN ({lst})")
```

Comment: I get a [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'IN' when I try to run this query. Looks like the braces are missing before IN, but not sure

Comment: Yes, Edited the answer could you check now?